# Finding out IP from client's FTP, so I can make a remote mySQL connection

Tags: php, wordpress

I would rather have the DB locally on their server but do not have access to their cpanel, or anything. This is my first time dealing with this problem.

I'm trying to make a safe remote connection through my webhost(which hosts the DB) to my client's FTP that was provided. I grabbed the FTP's IP and added it to the remote DB list on Bluehost. Still not connecting.

Any way I can do this? Is it secure?

edit: clarity

Comment: Very confused question. Do you mean your client's FTP client? What makes you think the data will be accessible by FTP? Even if the data files are accessible they may need to be exported / imported onto a different server. You make no mention of what OS are involved in this.

Comment: I actually have "client's FTP" but thought it would be confusing with an actual software client. Sorry for the confusion. I don't have cpanel access to their host, or I would have the DB on their host locally. I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the domain the database is on you can get the Ip by running 'tracert domainname.com' in the command line (windows) it'll show the IP next to the domain in [].

You should be able to use the domain rather than the IP though, but be aware many hosts (especially shared hosts) do not allow remote db access, or you may have to enable it in your hosting control panel.

It opens up access for remote users to your database, therefore it's a bit less secure - they will still need log in details, the biggest drawback is the speed will be quite a bit slower. I would recommend having the db on the same server (or network at least) as the website.

Comment: Bluehost has it and I did exactly this before, but it wasn't working. I'm going to try it with the domain name verbatim. Thanks!

Comment: if you're on a mac I think the command is traceroute instead of tracert

Comment: There is a mighty long list of IP addresses. I'm also finding out 2 backspace addresses. I'm going to try using those.

Comment: I'm guessing that bluehost suggest you specify the mysql host in PHP as 'localhost', I'd check their FAQs, if they give you a url/IP you could use that in your wordpress setup. If you can't see it then I'd email their support team, that can often be quicker in my experience - depending on their support of course...

Comment: also if traceroute is giving a long list of IPs you'll need the one (usually at the very top) next to the domain name you're checking against, all the other ones are just intermediate ones you can ignore

Comment: I've done a remote connection from my end before, but I can't seem to get the right IP address in there since it seems to be using backspace cloud hosting...

Comment: I'll make this the answer, but the client just coughed up the backspace login, so now I'm back to where I wanted to be... hah. Thanks anyways!